# Tikz bend edges 'adding arrowhead'

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, edge

So i am trying to make a flowchart with tikz. Everything was working fine and as expected. But then I tried to specify starting and endpoints of edges between some rectangles and out of nowhere tikz seems to add an additional arrowhead to the start of my edge.

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,thick]
        \node[draw,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (test1) {test1};
        \node[draw,
        left=of test1,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (test2) {test2};
        \draw[-latex] (test1.180) edge [bend left=45] (test2.-90);
        \draw[-latex] (test1) edge [bend right=45] (test2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For some reason the first edge has an additional arrowhead at the start of the edge (at node test1). How do I get rid of the unwanted arrowhead?

Also, is there a way for an edge starting at a rectangle node to properly fill out the empty space near the border?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I would define edge as shown in MWE below:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, thick, 
              minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm},
every edge/.style = {draw, -latex, thick} % <---
                        ]
\node[box] (test1) {test 1};
\node[box, left=of test1] (test2) {test 2};
%
\draw   (test1.180) edge [bend left=45] (test2.-90) 
        (test1)     edge [bend right=45] (test2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works... even though I don't quite see the difference between the code.

Comment: @Max_M, difference is that command `\draw` doesn't use options for edge style. Their style is defined in tikzpicture` preamble, code line is marked by `% <---` .